# How exactly lambda work ? c# and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I found the solution for start thread with arguments with lambda expression.

```
Thread amazonBuy1 = new Thread(() => amazon.Buy("Lego", visa, dhl));
```

So, my question is - How exactly does lambda work ?
How is it possible to give an method with params where it not possible as default, when speaking of thread argument.

Thank you.

Comment: The short version of @marc-gravell's answer is that it creates what's called a "closure", so that the `amazon`, `visa` and `dhl` variables are accessible to the lambda method when it's run. There's plenty of good resources online that explain how to use closures, and Marc's answer provides details of how they are implemented in C#, should you be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take your call:

```
Thread amazonBuy1 = new Thread(() => amazon.Buy("Lego", visa, dhl));
```

...and refactor it into two separate lines we get this:

```
ThreadStart threadStart = () => amazon.Buy("Lego", visa, dhl);
Thread amazonBuy1 = new Thread(threadStart);
```

So the constructor to `Thread` doesn't take the `"Lego"`, `visa`, `dhl` parameters at all - it simply takes a `ThreadStart` delegate.

A delegate is a variable that can be used to invoke a method. In this case the delegate can run `amazon.Buy("Lego", visa, dhl)` when invoked.

This means that the thread can start and then call the delegate *from inside the new thread*.

The compiler does all of the magic to allow `visa` and `dhl` to get bundled up inside the delegate. This is called a "closure". The compiler produces a delegate that *closes* over the two variables.

Answer (score 4):

Allow me to demonstrate what  the compiler does there:

```
class __horribleTypeName {
    public Something amazon;
    public SomethingElse visa;
    public AnotherSomething dhl;
    public void __horribleMethodName() {
        amazon.Buy("Lego", visa, dhl);
    }
}

...

var __horribleLocalName = new __horribleTypeName();
__horribleLocalName.amazon = ... // etc
Thread amazonBuy1 = new Thread(__horribleLocalName.__horribleMethodName);
```

Make sense? So the lambda contents become the method body of a compiler-generated method. The locals you access inside the body are lifted to fields on the compiler-generated instance. Note that the actual names used here are all "unpronouncable" - they cannot be expressed in C# - they are not legal C# identifiers (but are legal IL identifiers). The above is a simple example - there are other optimizations that  the compiler can do in some circumstances, including hoisting things to a reused static delegate instance (when no context is captured). Note also that  if `visa` or `dlh` or `amazon` are *instance fields*, then what you capture is `this`, not the fields themselves; so it could be:

```
class __horribleTypeName {
    public YourType __this;
    public void __horribleMethodName() {
        __this.amazon.Buy("Lego", __this.visa, __this.dhl);
    }
}
...
var __horribleLocalName = new __horribleTypeName();
__horribleLocalName.__this = this;
Thread amazonBuy1 = new Thread(__horribleLocalName.__horribleMethodName);
```

As a side note: if you want to pass in state to a thread, there is a `ParameterizedThreadStart`.

Comment: What isn't clear to me from this description is that the local variables are lifted in the method where the thread is started as well. Otherwise we would only refer to stale copies of the method changes them later on.

Comment: @Voo indeed; to use the first example, it isn't that *the value* of `amazon` is lifted just before the thread-start; **all mentions** of `amazon` in the original method are actually talking to `__horribleLocalName.amazon`; the *variable  itself* is relocated

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to emphasize this, since I feel this might get lost as it is in the current answer.

Answer (score 0):

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function and it is mostly used to create delegates in LINQ. Simply put, it's a method without a declaration, i.e., access modifier, return value declaration, and name. Convenience. It's a shorthand that allows you to write a method in the same place you are going to use it.

**Source:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397687.aspx

Your `Thread` takes a delegate called [`ThreadStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx). So when you use lambda like this, you're creating the delegate method on the fly.

Comment: Edited. And yes it does? He asked what lambda is and what it does. Which is exactly what it tells him.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete, as it doesn't describe the fact that a closure is created for the lambda.